# Shrinking one cell in a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to shrink one cell in the table, but it refuses to shring..here is my table.

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="position: absolute;width: 990px;margin-left: 8px;"  align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr class='no-wrap'>
            <th width="20%"></th>
            <th width="10%">Our Rating</th>
                        <th width="10%">Users' Rating</th>
            <th width="30%">Review</th>
            <th width="30%">Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<tr>
<td width="20%"></td>
                    <td width="10%">Our Rating</td>
                                    <td width="10%">Users' Rating</td>
                    <td width="30%">Review</th>
                    <td width="30%">Price</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that the review part doesnt shrink..even when I give it a lower percentage..why is that?

Comment: Does the column contain values that prevent it from shrinking?

Comment: you're closing the review column in the `tbody` with a `th` instead of a `td`

Comment: Dmitry, try to set `<table style="table-layout:fixed">` then the browser will use your column sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect HTML syntax.

You need to wrap your table row elements in `tr`:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <td></td>...
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also you have a `</th>` where you should have a `<td>` on your 2nd row, 4th cell (Review):

```
<td width="30%">Review</th>
```

Comment: sorry , i did wrap it in tr.. i forgot to put it into this example

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd How about my 2nd point? Regarding `</th>`